# Polynomials in vector spaces

Tags: vector-spaces

> Determine whether the following system of vectors is linearly dependent or independent.
>
> $$1+2x+3x^2+x^3, \, 2+5x-x^2+x^3, \, -3+2x-4x^2-2x^3 \in P_3(\mathbb{R})$$

How can I determine this when the problem involves polynomials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose a basis for $P_3$, might I suggest $1,x,x^2,x^3$

In this basis, your vectors are $(1,2,3,1), (2,5,-1,1),(-3,2,-4,-2)$

And, you should know how to show that those are (or are not) linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the isomormphism theorem. It tells about the *isomomorphism* of an abstract vector space to some ordinary vector space, say, $\mathbb{R}^4$.

To solve this problem, you must note that this set of polynomials belongs to $P_3$, so they can be written as an linear combination of the following polynomials:
$ B = \{ 1,x,x^2,x^3 \}$.
You can see that the set $B$ is, by definition, a *basis* for $P_3$. Since $P_3$ has four elements in its basis, we say that $P_3$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$.
So, you can write the polynomials using coordinate vectors with respect to the basis B. The polynomials in your question will be these ones:
$$(1,2,3,1),(2,5,-1,1),(-3,2,-4,-2)$$
So, we know from isomorphism theorem that, if this set of vectors of $\mathbb{R}^4$ is linearly independent, then so will be your set of polynomials. The same holds if the set is lineraly dependent. 
Basically, all you have to do is check if the coordinate vectors are either linearly dependent or not.

Answer (score 1):

Just take $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$a(1+2x+3x^2+x^3)+b(2+5x-x^2+x^3)+c(-3+2x-4x^2-2x^3)=0.$$

So we get $(a+2b-3c)+(2a+5b+2c)x+(3a-b-4c)x^2+(a+b-2c)x^3=0$. Then we have the system $$\begin{cases}
a+2b-3c=0 \\
2a+5b+2c=0 \\
3a-b-4c=0 \\
a+b-2c=0
\end{cases}$$

Now, it's just a matter of solving the above system to deduce if your vectors are linearly independent or not.